# find: missing argument to `-exec' when used in bash in a Chef recipe

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, escaping, chef-recipe

I need to substitute a string inside several files under a directory in Linux using bash.  This command works fine from the command line:

```
find ./ -iname '*.xml' -exec sed -i -e 's/<value>string<\/value>/<value>string01<\/value>/g' {} \;
```

When I try to put it in a shell using bash I obtain this error:

> STDERR: find: missing argument to `-exec'

UPDATE: My bash code is inside a Chef recipe.  Here's the code:

```
bash "change_string_dir" do
    code <<-EOH
         find ./ -iname '*.xml' -exec sed -i -e 's/<value>string<\/value>/<value>string01<\/value>/g' {} \;
    EOH
end
```

Comment: Would you please edit your Q to include more of the script, and the command by which you invoke it?  Are you using `#!/bin/bash` on line 1?  Is `STDERR:` actually printed on screen, or is that your comment so we know which pipe it's on?  I suspect you are using another program that captures I/O, and that other program may be part of the problem.

Comment: I've updated my question ....

Comment: Try `code <<-'EOH'` (with single-quotes around `EOH`) to disable Ruby interpretation of the string contents.  I suspect Ruby is swallowing the backslash before the semicolon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `code<<` line to `code <<-'EOH'` (with single-quotes around `EOH`).  This will [disable Ruby interpretation of the string contents](https://makandracards.com/makandra/15003-how-to-ruby-heredoc-without-interpolation).  Ruby is swallowing the backslash before the semicolon.  Example (in `irb`; `**...` added):

```
irb(main):004:0> print <<XX     ** No single-quotes
irb(main):005:0" \;
irb(main):006:0" XX
;                               ** the backslash is gone
=> nil
irb(main):007:0> print <<'XX'   ** with single-quotes
irb(main):008:0' \;
irb(main):009:0' XX
\;                              ** the backslash is still there
=> nil
```

Since Ruby is stripping the backslash-semicolon at the end of your `find` command line, `find` never sees the end of the arguments to `-exec`.

### Edit

For versions of Ruby not supporting non-interpolated here-docs, escape the contents manually.  E.g.:

```
find ./ -iname '*.xml' -exec sed -i -e 's/<value>string<\\/value>/<value>string01<\\/value>/g' {} \\;
                                                         ^ extra backslashes  - - -^- - - - - - - -^
```

`irb` example:

```
irb(main):001:0> print <<-EOH   ** No quotes
irb(main):002:0" \\;            ** Extra backslash
irb(main):003:0" EOH
\;                              ** The backslash is printed
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me ... Unfortunately for Chef  `code <<- 'EOH'` is a sintax error

Comment: @Cesare Edited - try escaping manually.  **Also** did you really do `<<- 'EOH'` (with a space after the hyphen)?  If so, try it without the space --- `<<-'EOH'`

Comment: Ok it's working now .... I use `find ./ -iname '*.xml' -exec sed -i -e 's/<value>string<\\/value>/<value>string01<\\/value>/g'  \\;` and NO need to use `code <<- 'EOH'`, so I continue to use `code <<- EOH` as in my original code